# Combining xml results within two foreach loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a result coming from a SoapClient which has been converted into XML. From that I have two foreach loops, one for the data and another to show the agents that use the data. The table of date has multiple entries for each agent due to a different type of entry name e.g. SALE - GAS or SALE ELECTRIC. What I want to do is combine the count and the talk duration so there is only one agent from these results.

Here is the code:

```
$xmlArray = xml2array($xml);
if( isset($xmlArray["data"]) 
&& isset($xmlArray["data"]["Report.Disposition.Summary3"]) 
&& isset($xmlArray["data"]["Report.Disposition.Summary3"]["row"]) )
{

$rows = $xmlArray["data"]["Report.Disposition.Summary3"]["row"];
if( count($rows) > 0 )
{
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        //$userDataArray = $row["@attributes"];         
        //var_export($userDataArray);                                           

        $UserId = $row["@attributes"]['UserId'];
        $Count = $row["@attributes"]['Count'];  
        $Code = $row["@attributes"]['Code'];
        $TalkDuration = $row["@attributes"]['TalkDuration'];    


        $company = $_SESSION['user']['company']; $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE company = '".$company."' AND agent_id = '".$UserId."'");
        $sth->execute();
        $agents = $sth->fetchAll(); 

        foreach($agents as $name){
            if(($Code == "1327 SALE - DUAL FUEL SWITCH") || ($Code == "1328 SALE - ELECTRICITY SWITCH") || ($Code == "1329 SALE - GAS SWITCH") || ($Code == "122 CLAIM STARTED BANK REFUNDS") || ($Code == "12202 CLAIM STARTED PBA")){ 
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$name['firstname'].' '.$name['lastname'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$Count.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.gmdate("H:i:s", $TalkDuration).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the result that it produces:

Gareth Wright   77  21:27:36

Gareth Wright   17  04:11:23

Gareth Wright   5   00:46:13

Chloe Delgado   82  20:42:26

Chloe Delgado   16  04:07:49

Chloe Delgado   3   00:43:58

Sophie Berrill  5   01:35:52

Sophie Berrill  1   00:19:38

Tom Pearson 84  00:56:40

Tom Pearson 15  04:10:46

Tom Pearson 3   01:03:23

Sean Lee    93  03:00:09

Sean Lee    12  03:10:12

Sean Lee    2   00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must build a array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    '0' => array(
        'firstname' => "Gareth",
        'lastname' => "Wright",
        'count' => 77,
        'talkDuration' => 'a date...'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'firstname' => "Gareth",
        'lastname' => "Wright",
        'count' => 17,
        'talkDuration' => 'a other date...'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        '...' => '...'
    )
);
```

How ? Like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    //some process like getting $agent and $count, ...
    foreach($agents as $name){
        $arr[] = array(
            'firstname' => $name['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $name['lastname'],
            'count' => $count,
            'talkDuration' => $TalkDuration
        );
    }
}
```

So after your two foreach, run this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $data) {
    $name = $data['firstname']."_".$data['lastname'];
    if (isset($result[$name])) {
        $result[$name]['count'] = $result[$name]['count']+$data['count'];
        $result[$name]['talkDuration'] = $result[$name]['talkDuration']+$data['talkDuration'];
    } else {
        $result[$name] = $data;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
print_r($result);
=================
Array
(
    [Gareth_Wright] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => Gareth
        [lastname] => Wright
        [count] => 94
        [talkDuration] => a date...
    )

    [...] => ...

)
```

Comment: I just get this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: This error mean that your first argument in foreach isn't a array. Before to use my code, you must get something like my `$arr` variable. Then you can use the foreach.

Comment: so do I need to build that array within a foreach loop as well to build the array for all the results?

Comment: for your edit the talkduration is in seconds so can be combined in the same way as the count 

$result[$name]['talkDuration'] = $result[$name]['talkDuration']+$data['talkDuration'];